# Switch statement not matching all conditions

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I must be missing something here. I'm counting up a list, and want to skip over specific numbers, so I made a switch statement:

```
$locationNumber = 00
DO {
    $locationNumber++
    switch ($locationNumber) {
    21 {$locationNumber++}
    31 {$locationNumber++}
    43 {$locationNumber++}
    44 {$locationNumber++}
    49 {$locationNumber++}
    51 {$locationNumber++}
    }
    Write-Host $locationNumber
} while ($locationNumber -lt 53)
```

Here's the output:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
44
45
46
47
48
50
52
53

Notice that 44 shows up, even though I have no breaks. Can someone tell me why/a way around this?

Comment: When you hit 43 in the switch statement it is not passed to the switch statement, but instead output with the increment. You'd see the same occur if you did 50 instead of 51.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is the switches `default` clause.

If you move the `Write-Host` to `default` in the switch statement, this means that if the other conditions are not met, then *default* to this action.

```
$locationNumber = 00
DO {
    $locationNumber++
    switch ($locationNumber) {
    21 {}
    31 {}
    43 {}
    44 {}
    49 {}
    51 {}
    default {Write-Host $locationNumber}
    }
} while ($locationNumber -lt 53)
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the default will only happen if none of the conditions are met? Yea, that makes sense, and thanks for helping, but I think what I'm trying to achieve overall won't work with the default statement. Appreciate the help though! Sorry I wasn't able to mark your answer the right one. I have since figured it out, I placed my solution somewhere below yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **eliminate a fixed set of numbers** - `21, 31, 43, 44, 49, 51` - **from a series of numbers** - `1` through `53`:

```bsh
$(
  switch (1..53) {
    { $_ -notin 21, 31, 43, 44, 49, 51 } { $_ }
  }
) -join ' '
```

The above yields (line-wrapped for readability) - note how all the numbers in the list above are missing:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 30 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 45 46 47 48 50 52 53
```

To capture the numbers in an *array*, simply assign to a variable in lieu of the `$(...)`:
`$nums = switch { ... }`

The above takes advantage of the following features:

- `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), to create a series of integers as an array.
- the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement accepting [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as branch conditionals, in which the input object at hand, `$_` can be tested via arbitrary expressions.
- the [`-notin` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-notin), which tests a scalar LHS for not being contained in a RHS collection.

---

As for **what you tried**:

By applying `++` to the numbers you wanted to skip, they were nonetheless printed by the `Write-Host` statement executed *in the same iteration of the `do` statement*, after the `switch` statement.

[Andrew Ryan Davis' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234178/45375) shows a solution to that problem via the `default` branch.
While the solution above is much more concise, Andrew's answer is actually faster, though that will likely not matter in practice.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @IDon'tKnowAnything, but if my problem formulation at the top correctly captures your intent and the solution works accordingly, then there must be a problem with your own solution, which yields a different result and whose approach I recommend against, because it's hard to reason about.

Comment: The difference in results being I do not have 45 in my list? Because I realized afterwards I also want to skip 45.

Comment: @IDon'tKnowAnything I see, but its more important for your answer to be _consistent with your question_ - the specific numbers are incidental to the problem. Given that others have already given answers based on the question as stated, I suggest modifying your answer to match it too (rather than edit the question and thereby invalidate the other answers).

Comment: @IDon'tKnowAnything: Similarly, it's not clear from the question why Andrew's answer wouldn't work - unless there's an additional requirement not stated in the question. In short: Please make sure all requirements are stated up front, and please don't post answers based on changing requirements (especially not without saying so).

Comment: That's understandable, I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Appreciate the help, but I just ended up doing

```
$locationNumber = 00
DO {
    $locationNumber++
    switch ($locationNumber) {
    21 {$locationNumber++}
    31 {$locationNumber++}
    43 {$locationNumber += 3}
    47 {$locationNumber++}
    49 {$locationNumber++}
    51 {$locationNumber++}
    }

    Write-Host $locationNumber
    
} while ($locationNumber -lt 53)
```

Where I added 3 to 43 to skip the ones I didn't need. Thanks.

Comment: Why 3, as that would remove 45 as well, and that is not in your skip list. What Andrew gave you is valid.

Comment: I did 3 because I realized I missed 45 in the original block of text.